# How to delete one row in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem when to deleting a row in `ListView` on android, I am using SQLite.

This is my class to delete a file (only need remove item the in database).

```
    public void deleteCallWhenUploadSuccess(String fileNameWhis)
    {
        db = callDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String where = CallDatabaseHelper.FILE_NAME + "=" + fileNameWhis;
        db.delete(CallDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, where, null);
    }
```

And in class, I call to using this.

```
dao.deleteCallWhenUploadSuccess(filename);
```

But it throws exception:

```
e: "sqlite.SQLiteException: near "2016": syntax error (code 1):, while compiling:

DELETE FROM recordStatus WHERE fileName=109092 2016-03-17 01.018.03.mp3"
```

Seem it missing `"` mark near `WHERE "fileName`

I tried to add:

`String where = CallDatabaseHelper.FILE_NAME + "=" + "'"'" + fileNameWhis;`

But the error still exists. How to pass this error? And use DELETE statement to delete a file with `fileName`, in this case, it has many spaces and special characters in `fileName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

- I would do a console log that spits out the file name at the top of the function, so you know its coming in formatted correctly
- As pointed out in the other answer you also need to get a writeable database.
- Use Where and WhereArgs in your query:

  ```
  db = callDatabaseHelper.getWriteableDatabase();
  String where = CallDatabaseHelper.FILE_NAME + " = ?";
  String [] whereArgs = new String[] {fileNameWhis}
  db.delete(CallDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
  ```

This is a safer way of doing queries, and may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete this in an easier way

```
 db.delete(CallDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, CallDatabaseHelper.FILE_NAME  + "=?", new String[]{fileNameWhis});
```

Comment: I don't know `YOURCONTRACT.CallDatabaseHelper.CONTENT_URI` is mean?